# Sqlalchemy+MS Access = Attempt to use a closed connection

Tags: ms-access, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy with MS Access db through sqlalchemy-access with pyodbc. So, after some amount of queries, it all falls with exception `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) Attempt to use a closed connection.`
Python 3.11 win10 x64

Short description of project: frontend uses ajax to load some info through flask-based API. When I started making my first page, all works correctly for a long time, about 50 page reboots (with total update of content) - and than it falls like now. Now I'm close to finish and my page makes much more queries to API, so, I can't even load page one time. But it's all lyrics.
I tried to update pyodbc to recent 5.0 version, it didn't happen.
I do not close connection manually, and I hardly believe that sqlalchemy does it itself.
I connected to db firstly using `?odbc_connect=`, tried also to create custom DSN in odbc manager, nothing helps.

Comment: Note that using the Access ODBC driver is explicitly not supported for servers, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9, both under details and under additional information. While we need more information to debug this, what you're trying to do is not a good idea.

Comment: @ErikA, thanks for this comment. I tried to use mssql server and imported data from accdb, now it works fine. I should keep compatibility with msaccess to support legacy forms for this db, so, mssql will be also fine for me. Thanks!